# Count occurrences in SQL

Tags: sql, select, count, pivot

I have a table with the following data

```
| id | type |
-------------
| 1  | a    |
| 1  | b    |
| 1  | a    |
| 2  | a    |
| 2  | b    |
| 3  | a    |
```

And I would like to have for each ID how many occurrences of each type there are

```
| id | a | b |
| 1  | 2 | 1 |
| 2  | 1 | 1 |
| 3  | 1 | 0 |
```

Is there a way in SQL (something like a pivot table)

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Is your values set limited to (a, b) or should it be dynamic?

Comment: Limited to a small set (<3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend conditional aggregation. This is a cross-database solution that is more flexible than vendor-specific solutions (and at least as efficient):

```
select
    id,
    sum(case when type = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) a,
    sum(case when type = 'b' then 1 else 0 end) b
from mytable
group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

On MS SQL Server you can use something like this (sample data is given by `values()` constructor) (I can't tell about other SQL flavours):

```
select * from (
    select id, t
    from (
        values 
            (1, 'a'),
            (1, 'b'),
            (1, 'a'),
            (2, 'a'),
            (2, 'b'),
            (3, 'a')
    ) z(id, t)
) x
pivot(count(t) for t in (a, b)) as y
```